# find the value of $a\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $2+\sqrt{3}$ is a root of the polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, radicals, cubics

Find the value of  $a\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $2+\sqrt{3}$ is  a root of the   polynomial

$$x^3-5x^2 +ax -1$$ 
I got   the answer    and value of $a = -10 -5\sqrt{3} -1$.

Is  my answer  is correct or not?

Comment: Does it check on your calculator? If so, it is probably correct and then there is no integer $a$ that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need
$$(2+\sqrt3)^3-5(2+\sqrt3)^2+a(2+\sqrt3)-1=0,$$ which gives
$$a=2-\sqrt3-(2+\sqrt3)^2+5(2+\sqrt3)=5$$

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg   im not getting   how can  directly  writes which gives
$$a=2-\sqrt3-(2+\sqrt3)^2+5(2+\sqrt3)=5$$...can u elaborate this more...

Comment: I just divided by $2+\sqrt3$ and $\frac{1}{2+\sqrt3}=2-\sqrt3$. Actually, I think this way is much better than to use that $a\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @   Michael Rozenberg   thanks a lot i got  it

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

If $2+\sqrt3$ is a root, then so is $2-\sqrt3$

If $x$ is the third root, then by Vieta's theorem we have:

$$(2+\sqrt3)*(2-\sqrt3)*x=1$$
as $1$ is the free coefficient

Hence $x=1$

Then again, by Vieta's theorem:

$$a=(2+\sqrt3)*1+(2-\sqrt3)*1+(2+\sqrt3)*(2-\sqrt3)=5$$

Comment: thanks asdf....

Answer (score 2):

If $a \in \mathbb Z$, then if $2+\sqrt3$ is a root, then so is $2-\sqrt3$.

Therefore, $x^3-5x^2 +ax -1$ is divisible by $x^2 - 4 x + 1$, which has $2\pm\sqrt3$ as roots.

Now, $x^3-5x^2 +ax -1 = (x^2 - 4 x + 1)(x-1)+(a-5)x$ and so $a=5$.